# Index error on executing DDL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ddl

When I run the DDL mentioned below in sql server, I'm getting an error as:

> "Warning! The maximum key length for a clustered index is 900 bytes.
>   The index 'TBL_MyTable' has maximum length of 1278 bytes.  For some
>   combination of large values, the insert/update operation will fail."

Just wondering how do I resolve this error?

Thanks.

```
BEGIN

DECLARE @constraint_name nvarchar(256)
DECLARE @table_name nvarchar(256)
DECLARE @col_name nvarchar(256)


SET @table_name = N'TBL_MyTable'
SET @col_name = N'myDate'

SELECT @constraint_name = CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE 
    where TABLE_NAME = @table_name AND COLUMN_NAME = @col_name  

    IF @constraint_name IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            EXEC('ALTER TABLE [dbo].['+ @table_name +'] DROP CONSTRAINT ' + @constraint_name);          
        END 
            EXEC('ALTER TABLE [dbo].['+ @table_name +'] ALTER COLUMN myDate DATE NOT NULL');            

            EXEC('ALTER TABLE [dbo].['+ @table_name +'] ADD CONSTRAINT 
            [PK_TBL_MyTable] 
            Primary Key 
                 (  column1,
                    myDate,
                    column2,
                    column3,
                    column4,
                    column5,
                    column6)')

END
```

Comment: It's a warning, not an error. You resolve it by making the index key smaller. You can either remove columns entirely, or move some columns out of the key and instead use the INCLUDE. It's also possible you can simply ignore the warning, depending on whether it really is possible to exceed 900 bytes on any specific row of actual data (just because the key *can* accept more than 900 bytes doesn't mean you will actually do that). We can't tell you how to do that optimally, though, without a LOT more information.

Comment: I strongly suggest against having a `PRIMARY KEY` composed of 7 columns. If we assumt that all of those columns (apart from `myDate`) are `nvarchar(256)`, that's 256 * 2 * 6 bytes of data, totalling 3072 bytes, plus your `mydate` column. WAY over the limit. Reconsider your `PRIMARY KEY` choice.

Comment: This code has potential error. The same field can be a part of PK and FK, so `@constraint_name` will be randomly assigned (multiple values will be assigned without causing any error), so this situation is possible: FK is assigned to `@constraint_name`, FK is dropped, then PK creation fails because another PK already exists, and and in the meanwhile referential integrity is lost.

Comment: Thanks all for your inputs.@Aaron, how do I use include keyword in my ddl above?

Comment: >>> how do I use include keyword in my ddl above<<< Your code creates CLUSTERED PK. It has all already included. Instead, try to find out what field is really key field, and make it the key, I doubt you need 7 fields to uniquely identify a row.